# Internationalization: Passing variables in HAML to YAML (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, haml, yaml

I have a syntax problem with internationalization in Rails/HAML/YAML with passing on JavaScript (?) variables to yaml when concatenating strings.

Before internationalization, the HAML file looked like this:

```
Dear {{order.name}},
```

I changed it, and the following works fine - in en.yml

```
en:
  salutation: "Dear %{customer_name},"
```

and in the HAML file:

```
= I18n.t('.salutation', customer_name: "Robert")
```

However, instead of "Robert" I want to assign it the value from {{order.name}}. The following does not work:

```
= I18n.t('.salutation', customer_name: {{order.name}})
= I18n.t('.salutation', customer_name: order.name)
= I18n.t('.salutation', customer_name: @order.name)
```

The workaround to leave the variables out of the yaml and build the strings in HAML with the {{variable}} syntax is not convenient, as we are using multiple yaml items at various places and it would be a mess to rip the strings apart (esp. for the translated files).

Thank you and sorry for the newbie question, but I could not find anything on the web...

Comment: which error is risen when you specify `I18n.t('.salutation', customer_name: @order.name)`?

Comment: `Dear {{order.name}},` does not look like HAML. That looks like liquid

Comment: Looks like some JS frontend framework for me.

Comment: {{order.name}} should be JS frontend (twitter bootstrap, if I'm correct).

Comment: @majioja: There is no real error message, the text just doesn't display...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to interpolate the string which you want to pass to the `I18n.t` method:

`= I18n.t('.salutation', customer_name: "#{order.name}")`

Note: I haven't tested this, but I believe it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work... However, I did find a solution by inserting the variable directly into the yml file: `salutation: "Dear {{order.name}},"`, and keeping the HAML file simple as: `= I18n.t '.salutation'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `{{order.name}}` as a string:

```
= I18n.t('.salutation', customer_name: '{{order.name}}')
```

This will output `Dear {{order.name}}`, as you expect.